# How to run mecab from another docker container

Tags: docker-compose, mecab

I created the following docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  mecab:
    #entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "sleep 2073600"]
    image: wgtdocker/mecab-0.996-alpin3.12:latest
    volumes:
      - mecab-volume:/usr/local/bin
      - tmp-volume:/tmp
    links:
      - web
  
  web:
    entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "sleep 2073600"]
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - mecab-volume:/usr/local/bin
      - tmp-volume:/tmp
volumes:
  mecab-volume:
  tmp-volume:
```

and run docker-compose up --build -d

```
     Name                    Command               State    Ports
-----------------------------------------------------------------
vagrant_mecab_1   mecab -d /usr/local/lib/me ...   Exit 0        
vagrant_web_1     sh -c sleep 2073600              Up
```

and run docker-compose exec web sh
and run ls -lt /tmp

```
/go # ls -lt /tmp
total 8
drwxrwxr-x    9 root     root          4096 Aug 15 12:24 mecab-ipadic-neologd-0.0.6
drwxr-xr-x    8 11152    5000          4096 Aug 15 12:23 mecab-0.996
```

and run ls -lt /usr/local/bin/mecab

```
/go # ls -lt /usr/local/bin/mecab
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         19800 Aug 15 10:45 /usr/local/bin/me-cab
```

so I run mecab --help but this application is not working with the following error

```
Error loading shared library libmecab.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/mecab)
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/mecab: mecab_do: symbol not found
```

after that run find / -name libmecab.so.2

```
/go # find / -name libmecab.so.2
/tmp/mecab-0.996/src/.libs/libmecab.so.2
```

Should I install mecab again?
but I would like to complete the issue without reinstall

If you have something idea let me know

Comment: Can you add your image's Dockerfile; how are you installing this application?  Why are you trying to share `/tmp` between containers?

Comment: You can see this resource to check the following git repository,
https://github.com/wgtgithub/mecab-docker-compose

Comment: Yes
I got completed this issue
I modified docker-compose file about volumes
and I should modify mecab-docker repository also for remove in /tmp
thanks

Comment: I removed the above docker image repository already
And push another repository instead of it
You can check the new one at the following GitHub repository ,
https://github.com/wgtgithub/vagrant-mecab-flask-restful-api-docker-compose